# how to match function code block with regex

Tags: visual-studio, regex

What I like to do is remove all functions which has specific word for example, if the word is 'apple':

```
void eatapple()
{
// blah
// blah
}
```

I'd like to delete all code from '`void`' to '`}`'.
What I tried is:

```
^void.*apple(.|\n)*}
```

But it took very long time I think something is wrong here.

I'm using Visual Studio. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did it.

```
^void.*(a|A)pple\(\)\n\{\n((\t.*\n)|(^$\n))*^\}
```

Answer (score 3):

To clarify jeong's eventual solution, which I think is pretty clever: it works, but it depends on the code being formatted in a very particular way. But that's OK, because most IDE's can enforce a particular formatting standard anyway.  If I may give a related example - the problem that brought me here - I was looking to find expressions of the form (in Java)

```
if (DEBUG) { 
  // possibly arbitrary statements or blocks
}
```

which, yes, isn't technically regular, but I ran the Eclispe code formatter on the files to make sure they all necessarily looked like this (our company's usual preferred code style):

```
if (DEBUG) {
  statement();
  while (whatever) {
    blahblahblah(etc);
  }
  // ...
}
```

and then looking for this (this is Java regex syntax, of course)

```
^(\s*)if \(DEBUG.*(?:\n\1  .*)*\n\1\}
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Function blocks aren't regular, so using a regular expression in this situation is a bad idea.

If you really have a huge number of functions that you need to delete (more than you can delete by hand (suggesting there's something wrong with your codebase — but I digress)) then you should write a quick brace-counting parser instead of trying to use regular expressions in this situation.

It should be pretty easy, especially if you can assume the braces are already balanced. Read in tokens, find one that matches "apple", then keep going until you reach the brace that matches with the one immediately after the "apple" token. Delete everything between.

Comment: @Welbog, I don't think counting braces is an easy program to write. If it has to be error free, the program must be capable of understanding the source just like the compiler.

Comment: @Codism: Counting braces is simple. You just have to watch out for gotchas like braces within comments and string literals. You're right that in order to be error-free you need to write a context-free parser for it, but that is the level of complexity of this task. A brace counter should be fine as long as there are no gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, regular language is not able to express a sentence described by context free grammar. If it is a one time job, why don't you just do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to VI. Then you can select the opening brace and press `d%` to delete the section.

Comment: The percent sign moves to matching braces, brackets, and parentheses.